# Php - Textbox values to array is replacing

Tags: php, arrays, web

I'm trying have a array which store the text box values, but my problem is whenever I run my code the first text is always being replace when I add another text, this "another text" will remain until I add a third text. And so, this process will repeat and repeat annndd repeat.

Please tell me wath I'am missing.

```
<body>

<?php
    $server_name="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="mabangis";
    $connection=mysqli_connect($server_name,$username,$password,$database) or die('not connect');

    $final_value1="";

    if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        $arraytextbox_value=$_POST['array'];
        foreach($arraytextbox_value as $final_value)
        {
            $final_value1="$final_value<br>";
        }

        echo "$final_value1";
    }
?>

    <form method="POST" action="Prac-1.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="array[]">
        <button type="add" name="insert">Add</button>
        <button type="save">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your explanation is not quite clear. Where does the text stay? In the text box or where? Also, your $items array is not populated. Also, you echo an array. All wrong with your code

Comment: this code is incomplete.  I can't even imagine how many PHP errors you are throwing up with this.  I honestly don't even see how you are getting any kind of answer with this code.

Comment: Your $_POST['array'] variable will always be overwritten by your next submission. It will always only contain the last text you submitted. If you want the text to persist, you will have to save it to a database. Or if it works for you, add several more input text fields.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess, this is not my original code. wait, i'll update it.

Comment: @AmmoPT I'am aware about on saving it in the database, but is there really no other way to store many text box values to an array?

Comment: @PurpleViolet Yes, you can create more text boxes with the name of `array[]` and they will all be submitted at the same time, to the same $_POST['array'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more form fields like this

```
<form method="POST" action="Prac-1.php">
   First Name: <input type="text" name="array[]">
   Second Name: <input type="text" name="array[]">
    <button type="add" name="insert">Add</button>
    <button type="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

And change the php code like this

```
$names = array();
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $arraytextbox_value=$_POST['array'];
    foreach($arraytextbox_value as $final_value)
    {
        $names[]="$final_value";
    }

    print_r($names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
<?php
$_POST['insert'] = 'save';
$_POST['array'] = ['apple','orange'];

$final_value1="";

if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $arraytextbox_value=$_POST['array'];
    foreach($arraytextbox_value as $final_value)
    {
        // concatenating assignment operator to join the strings
        $final_value1 .= "$final_value<br>";
    }

    echo "$final_value1";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use implode()

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    echo $final_value1 = implode('<br>', $_POST['array']);
}
```

OUTPUT: `"apple<br>orange"`

DEMO:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/985b7c68d5cdfe86d6cfe8d6768e05d051c958c2